# Alternative of reshape () of matlab in R?

Tags: r, matlab, tiff

I want to implement reshape(X3, [ ], 5) command which i use in matlab in R

I have `X3.tif` file ( 200 * 150*5)
nrows = 200 ncols= 150 and nbands = 5

I use this command to save tif in datafeame

```
a <- brick('X3.tif')
```

X3 is a 3D data but I want to save it as matrix of dimension
[ (200*150) * 5 ]
so that I have ( nbands as number of colums )

If a use :

```
A <- as.data.frame.matrix(a)
```

it stores matrix of dimension 200*150 and eliminates the nband =5

Thanks

Comment: Just try `A<-a[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're looking for is this:

```
#Sample matrix
myMatrix <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8))
myMatrix 
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4
[5,]    5
[6,]    6
[7,]    7
[8,]    8
```

Try this:

```
myMatrix_new <- matrix(myMatrix, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
myMatrix_new

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    5    6    7    8
```

Under help `?matrix` you can find the arguments `nrow`, `ncol`, `byrow` which allows you to set the number of rows, columns and automatically, if you'd like.